# Fixing minimal number of lines for page break in given group type (paragraph, section, chapter etc)

Tags: page-breaking

I'm wondering if I can avoid having paragraphs / sections etc starting or end at pages where there are only a few lines within their proper group. More precisely, can I fix a minimal number of lines for which a paragraph is allowed to break to the next page ? Conversely, can I fix a minimal number of lines for which a paragraph is allowed to begin at the previous page ? Of course I would like to do this once and for all, instead of fixing each part by hand.

Here are three pictures of things that I would like to avoid. The first one shows a section beginning at the bottom of one page with only two lines before breaking. The second one shows a break and a few words before an equation (I'd like the words "limit N -> infinity:" to be on the previous page and the equation to be after the break). The third one shows a proposition which I would like being written on one page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see the widows-and-orphans package for a semi-automatic way to control things here

Comment: you can set widow and orphan penalties to prevent a single line but that usually does not have a good outcome, your limit N ->\infty  line for example, if you just prevent a single line being carried over, tex will carry over two leaving the page short. It is better to try `\looseness=-1` to see if that paragraph could be set in one line less, or using `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to allow one extra line on the previous page.

Comment: Where should I put the command \enlargethispage{\baselineskip} ?

Comment: anywhere on the top level of previous page

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.